# does anyone had success in posting from android emulator to GAE?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

does anyone had success in POSTing from android emulator to GAE? I am trying and I am getting Unknown Host Exception.

Do I need to do some settings in emulator? Please help me. I am using HttpClient and HttpPost, and also set uses INTERNET permission.

Answer (score 2):

I did post to GAE in an application I wrote about a year ago at the university, but didn't have any special problems. What do you mean exactly by posting to GAE? Posting to a webapp deployed on a publicly accessible GAE? Or behind authentication? Or locally on your development environment??

If you want to access GAE running locally on your development environment, you need to use this IP: "10.0.2.2" which represents your local machine, basically your webapp would then be at http://10.0.2.2:8080 (see [my post here](http://blog.js-development.com/2009/10/accessing-host-machine-from-your.html) for more details about that)

Otherwise, if you have issues with Google Authentication from your mobile Android app to a GAE hosted application, it is always good to take a look at open source apps which do the same and see how they handle it. Here are two which came just to my mind..

- http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/
- http://code.google.com/p/android2cloud/